# Fail to run "learnr_questions.Rmd" from exams2learnr

Tags: r-exams, learnr

I tried to run the example file "learnr_questions.Rmd" that comes as an example in exams2learnr package. The chunk:

```
exams2learnr("swisscapital.Rmd", allow_retry = TRUE, incorrect = "Incorrect, try again.")
```

generates "Invalid 'definition' argument" error.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Please install at least version 2.4-0 of the `exams` package.

**Notes:** This error seems to happen when using a recent version of `learnr` with the version 2.3-6 of `exams` (which was the CRAN release when the question was asked). As this wasn't a problem in older versions of `learnr`, the `exams2learnr` package claimed in its DESCRIPTION file that `exams` >= 2.3-6 was sufficient but this is not true anymore with more recent versions of `learnr`. Hence, I have just updated the DESCRIPTION of `exams2learnr` to correctly require `exams` >= 2.4-0.

Comment: Thanks, professor Achim. I did what you said. ("exams": ‘2.4.0’ ; "exams2learnr" : ‘0.1.0’; "learnr": ‘0.10.1’) The error persists. I will try to figure out an alternative.

Comment: An ugly way is to generate an R data file with R-exams questions using  "exams2learnr" (a list of questions for example), and then upload the data in the setup of the "learnr" document and use the questions and every chunk I want. I already did, but I feel very uncomfortable.

Comment: Professor Achim. Thanks for your time and patience. My problem was the R version I had installed: I updated my R and it works great! Thanks again! -Eduardo

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! R-Forge provides current windows boundaries only for the current version of R. If you have an older R version you need to install the source version rather than the binary. You can do so by adding `type = "source"` in the `install. packages` command (and you need to have the Rtools installed).